# boost::asio::async_read_until Don´t truncate the input message

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

i am trying to truncate a input message when the program read a specific character, for this i have the next code:

This is the ActiveSocketClientConnection.h

```
class ActiveSocketClientConnection : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<ActiveSocketClientConnection>{
private:

    boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> socket_;
    boost::asio::streambuf data_;

    ...

public:

    ...
}
```

This is the ActiveSocketClientConnection.cpp

```
void ActiveSocketClientConnection::handleConnect(const boost::system::error_code& error){

    std::string sETX;
    sETX.push_back(0x3A); //0x3A = :

    boost::asio::async_read_until(
        *socket_.get(),
        data_, 
        sETX.c_str(),
        boost::bind(&ActiveSocketClientConnection::handleReadBody,
            this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error
        )
   );
}

void ActiveSocketClientConnection::handleReadBody(  boost::system::error_code error){
    size_t t = data_.size();

    unsigned char* output = (unsigned char*)malloc(t);
    memcpy(output, boost::asio::buffer_cast<const void*>(data_.data()), t);

    data_.consume(t);

    ...
}
```

If i pass the message (for example) *AA:A* with a socket connection. The function *async_read_until* save all the message in *data_*, don´t truncate the message where the caracter *:* is present.

Someone could say me what i am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have undefined behaviour. You call `async_read_until` with `std::string_view` as a delimiter. But this view is created based on `std::string` which is local inside your handle function. `async_read_until` ends immediately, string as local is destroyed and you have dangling pointer inside string view (`std::string_view` doesn't make deep copy of string, it is just a pair: a pointer to data and its size).

As solution just call overload taking `char`:

```
boost::asio::async_read_until(
    *socket_.get(),
    data_, 
    0x3A,  // <- added
    boost::bind(&ActiveSocketClientConnection::handleReadBody,
        this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error
    )
```

);

---

Official [boost reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until/overload1.html) states:

> After a successful async_read_until operation, the dynamic buffer
>   sequence may **contain additional data beyond the delimiter**. An
>   application will typically leave that data in the dynamic buffer
>   sequence for a subsequent async_read_until operation to examine.

So you have to parse data looking for first occurence of delimiter and extract proper *subbuffer* of read data.